# Contact form not sending full submission data via php

Tags: php, html, email, contacts

I have an HTML contact form that uses javascript for a change function. I have a dropdown for the subject and based on what option the person chooses different fields are displayed. For example if they choose Bug report different fields appear than selecting Add my group. Whenever a user fills out the form not and it gets emailed to me their answers to the questions based on the subject theyve selected dont get emailed to me.

I have included the code below, any help appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#select").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "subject1") {
                $("#EVENT").show();
            } else {
                $("#EVENT").hide();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == "subject2") {
                $("#GROUPCLUBS").show();
            } else {
                $("#GROUPCLUBS").hide();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == "subject3") {
                $("#DIRECTORY").show();
            } else {
                $("#DIRECTORY").hide();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == "subject4") {
                $("#BUG").show();
            } else {
                $("#BUG").hide();
            }                     
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="name">Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label for="subject">Subject *</label>
</td>
 <td valign="top">

<select name="subject" id="select">
  <option value="">-- select an option --</option>
  <option value="subject1">Add an Event</option>
  <option value="subject2">Add my Group or Club</option>
  <option value="subject3">I want listed in the Business Directory</option>
  <option value="subject4">Submit a Bug Report</option>
  <option value="subject5">Other Questions</option>
</select>

<div id="EVENT" style="display: none">
    <label for="EventDate">Event Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventdate" />
<br>
    <label for="EventTime">Event Time</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventtime" />
<br>
    <label for="EventLocation">Event Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventlocation" />
<br>
    <label for="EventDescription">Event Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventdescription" />
<br>
    <label for="Ticketinfo">Ticket Information</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventticketinfo" />
<br>
    <label for="ExtraInfo">Extra Info</label>
    <input type="text" name="extrainfo" />
<br>
    <label for="Website">Website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" />
<br>
    <label for="ContactInfo">Contact Info</label>
    <input type="text" name="contact" />
</div> 


<div id="GROUPCLUBS" style="display: none">
    <label for="ClubDescription">Club Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="clubdescription" />
<br>
    <label for="Meet">When does the club meet?</label>
    <input type="text" name="meeting" />
<br>
    <label for="Location">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="location" />
<br>
    <label for="Cost">Cost of joining</label>
    <input type="text" name="cost" />
<br>
    <label for="ExtraInfo">Extra Info</label>
    <input type="text" name="extrainfo" />
<br>
    <label for="ContactInfo">Contact Info</label>
    <input type="text" name="contact" />
</div> 


<div id="DIRECTORY" style="display: none">
    <label for="BusinessDescription">Business Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="businessdescription" />
<br>
    <label for="BusinessLocation">Business Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="location" />
<br>
    <label for="OpeningHours">Opening Hours</label>
    <input type="text" name="openinghours" />
<br>
    <label for="Website">Website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" />
<br>
    <label for="ContactInfo">Contact Info</label>
    <input type="text" name="contact" />
</div> 


<div id="BUG" style="display: none">
    <label for="device">Device</label>
    <input type="text" name="device" />
<br>
    <label for="info"></label>
    <strong>Please provide more details in the message box below</strong>
</div> 
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="message">Message *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="message" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "david@davidsthompson.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "New Contact Form";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required 
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required 

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';


    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    if(strlen($subject) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Subject you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }


  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}
?>
```

From the picture below you can see the information fields arnt being emailed.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA6Nt.png)

Comment: Take off the error suppression `@` on the mail function and see if you get any type of a verbose error.

Comment: @WebCode.ie I've included a picture on the original post showing which information isnt coming across to email

Comment: @Funk... can you open this back up? I was in the middle of writing an answer as I saw what the issue was. It's not related to the question you linked...

Comment: @WebCode.ie could you email me the solution? I have checked the question linked and its not related :/ david [at] davidsthompson.co.uk ?

Comment: @WebCode.ie Sure thing; go right ahead.

Comment: However @WebCode.ie this also looked like an exact repost of their previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529883/html-form-with-dropdown-change-function-not-submitting-via-php which also was added as a duplicate. So technically speaking; I wasn't in the wrong.

Comment: @WebCode.ie Are you able to advise of what you spotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send your collected variables to your email body like so..

After this...

```
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";
```

Add this...

```
$email_message .= "Event Date: ".clean_string($_POST['eventdate'])."\n";
$email_message .= "Event Time: ".clean_string($_POST['eventtime'])."\n";
//etc...
```

Repeat this for the form fields that you want to see in the email.

You should never really accept raw input from $_POST like you have and should instead filter it to prevent against attacks.

Also I notice you are attempting to prevent email header injection which is a great (and advised) practice however, change your `str_replace` function to `str_ireplace` to ensure someone can't enter `BCC` (etc) and not just `bcc` (lowercase) into your form fields.

Comment: Perfect its coming through however a few of the text fields are blank when information has been entered?

Comment: You need to do as I say in the answer... specifically: **Repeat this for the form fields that you want to see in the email.**

Comment: Done that however "extrainfo" "website" and "contact" are still coming through blank

Comment: I understand. I see you use those fields repeatedly in your form with the same name. The short answer is you need to make your field names unique. To counteract this, prefix these field names with something to make them unique per subject. So for the **event** subject, change the field name to this: `<input type="text" name="eventwebsite" />`  and then in the **directory subject** change the field name to this: `<input type="text" name="directorywebsite" />` - then update your PHP to read these fields.

Comment: I assume theres no way to get PHP to only send $email_message based on what options have been filled in instead of having every field possible come through to email?

Comment: Sure there is. Use condititions... `if/else` etc

Comment: Thank you, do you have any recommendations on where the best place for tutorials are to use and learn conditions?

Comment: Udemy.com is a good place to learn (at a small price) https://www.udemy.com/php-for-complete-beginners-includes-msql-object-oriented/